# Count the number of days an order has been at a specific status

Tags: sql-server, query, gaps-and-islands

I can't figure out how to write a query that returns the results I need.

Below is a table that list in chronological order the status of an order on specific days and time.

An order can change from one status to another but can also change back to a status it was at previously.

How do I write a query that will give me the following for each time an order changes a status (minimum days is 1):

```
select doc_no, doc_type, line_no, status, DATEDIFF(day, '04/18/2023', '05/10/2023') AS   [number of days at this status before changing]
```

Data:

| doc_no | doc_type | line_no | status | updated date | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 527 | 2023-02-17 00:00:00.000 | 100640 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 527 | 2023-03-16 00:00:00.000 | 114555 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 527 | 2023-03-23 00:00:00.000 | 101018 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 527 | 2023-03-23 00:00:00.000 | 145322 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 545 | 2023-03-23 00:00:00.000 | 145323 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 555 | 2023-03-23 00:00:00.000 | 145411 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 555 | 2023-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 113735 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 555 | 2023-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 115644 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 555 | 2023-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 115826 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 527 | 2023-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 122233 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 527 | 2023-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 190943 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 527 | 2023-04-18 00:00:00.000 | 32939 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 527 | 2023-04-18 00:00:00.000 | 161039 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 545 | 2023-04-18 00:00:00.000 | 161046 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 555 | 2023-04-18 00:00:00.000 | 161102 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 555 | 2023-04-18 00:00:00.000 | 163512 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 555 | 2023-05-09 00:00:00.000 | 134853 |
| 2353021 | SA | 21000 | 555 | 2023-05-10 00:00:00.000 | 140516 |

The results I am looking for:

| doc_no | doc_type | line_no | status | number_of_days_at_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2353021 | SA | 2100 | 527 | 27 |
| 2353021 | SA | 2100 | 545 | 1 |
| 2353021 | SA | 2100 | 555 | 22 |
| 2353021 | SA | 2100 | 527 | 4 |
| 2353021 | SA | 2100 | 545 | 1 |
| 2353021 | SA | 2100 | 555 | 22 |

Answer (score 2):

Below query will help you to get your desired results : see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d5e2/8)

Idea is to use the `LAG()` window function to get the previous row's `updated_date` and then calculate the number of days at each status using `DATEDIFF()` and filter the results to show only rows where the status has changed for a minimum of one day.

```
 WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    doc_no,
    doc_type,
    line_no,
    [status],
    updated_date,
    LAG(updated_date) OVER (PARTITION BY doc_no, line_no ORDER BY updated_date, [time]) AS prev_updated_date
  FROM order_status
)
SELECT 
  doc_no,
  doc_type,
  line_no,
  [status],
  DATEDIFF(day, prev_updated_date, updated_date) AS number_of_days_at_status
FROM CTE
WHERE prev_updated_date IS NOT NULL
  AND DATEDIFF(day, prev_updated_date, updated_date) >= 1
ORDER BY updated_date;
```